# Is it possible (feasible) to format (fold) Node.js terminal output JSON?

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, zsh, node.js

I'm a frontend developer, and I'm unfamiliar with command line tools for Node.js

I currently use iTerm with zShell, but I can't find any resources online about folding console output (similar to how the Chrome console formats objects). I tried using [fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx) but can't seem to pipe and utilize the Node output through the util.

```
node -e 'console.log({ a: { b: 2 } })';
node -e 'console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: { b: 2 } }, null, 2))';
```

For large network objects, it would be much more convenient to fold the nested layers. It would also be great to have syntax highlighting.

---

### Is there an easy way to debug Node.js console output JSON?

Am I missing fundamental CLI tools? I know this is a relatively open-ended question, but I think it would be a good resource for other people in my situation (I've spent ~3 hours researching with barely any improvement).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the first line is that `node` command doesn't produce valid JSON string when you use `console.log`. You need to encode the object as JSON string yourself.

The second line correctly encodes the object as JSON string (using `stringify`):

```
node -e 'console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: { b: 2 } }, null, 2))'
```

To pipe the JSON string output of the `node` command you need to omit the semicolon `;`. The semicolon in bash is used to separate commands. More information about what semicolon means in bash: [docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch28_16.htm](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch28_16.htm)

This is how you can pipe the ouptut to `fx`:

```
node -e 'console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: { b: 2 } }, null, 2))' | fx
```

And this is how you would pipe th output to `jq`:

```
node -e 'console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: { b: 2 } }, null, 2))' | jq
```

`fx` will be probably more intuitive to use.
`jq` might come in handy if you need to deal with large outputs.

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

Here is some information on how to install it: [stedolan.github.io/jq/download](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)

And here is a tutorial on how to do some basic filtering with `jq`: 
[stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/)

Comment: the commands provided throw some unexpected/expected token errors (`;`) .. any other way to pipe fx (for example to pass the entire dev server output) or isnt fx _that_ intelligent to be able to parse and detect json on the fly?

Answer (score 4):

It's worth mentioning that Node.js can be debugged by listening to `localhost:9229`

In my case:

1. I went to `chrome://inspect/#devices`
2. Opened Node.js debugger
3. changed `localhost:9229` to `127.0.0.1:9229` on 'Connections' panel ... this took a few hours to discover
4. made and ran a package.json command `"debug": "node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --config=jest.config.js --timeout=60000 --runInBand",`
5. accepted debugging in the Node.js sources panel and console.log didn't work, but watching variables was convenient

Answer (score 1):

## View Logs with Google Chrome

1. Run your Node server with the `--inspect` flag

`$ node --inspect server.js`

2. Open a new tab in Google Chrome and go to `chrome://inspect/#devices`

[image]

3. Now click on `inspect` to view all logs with the browser console